# delete a folder to a specific user In Team Foundation Server (TFS)

Tags: c#, tfs

i want to delete the local copy of a folder for a specific user only. the user has already downloaded (checked in) the folder.

i have already tried the below things

i deleted the folder, but the problem is its deleting it from local and source control version as well.

i restricted user to access that by denying the read , check in , check out. but it only restricts the user to edit and check in and check out, i want to delete his local copy.

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this file has been downloaded locally. After you restricted the user to access the server version of the file. He won't see and get the folder in TFS server. However, there is no way or settings to delete his local copy.

These files are as same as offline, you can read, edit them even without connecting to TFS server. So you may need to distance to his machine and delete those local copy manually. Or send an e-mail ask him to delete them.